# Python pip install lxml not working

Tags: python, installation, pip, lxml

I am really trying to webscrape.

I run:

```
pip install lxml
```

then it starts downloading but at the end it says:

> `import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Bob\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-9dzvj0lp\\lxml\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Bob\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-mm2qmy4n-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Bob\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-9dzvj0lp\lxml`

I found code that everyone says works for them but wont for me.  It led me to the conclusion that it wasn't downloaded properly...

How can I resolve this?

Running Windows 10

Comment: This would probably be a more well-received if it were written more professionally. We hate fun!

Comment: haha really? im new here soooo ill try my hardest to be not funny.... but can u help me out? do i need to download xlml from their website first before doing that?  codecademy didnt really teach me this.

Comment: I edited your post to fit better to the standards here...

Comment: Okay, i see why.  Thanks for lookin out!

Comment: Good luck. I have enough trouble getting packages like this to build on OS X, I can't imagine doing it on Windows. :/

Comment: really yeah i have been reading that python is tricky with windows.. kinda annoying but i enjoy it but i really want to scrape and its bugging me that my code wont work due to lxml not DLing properly!!

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, I would suggest using the Anaconda distribution to install Python, and then use conda to install most of your packages. Windows can be a nightmare getting stuff set up, and Anaconda makes life much easier.

See here: 
https://www.continuum.io/downloads

Comment: can you explain in short how this would help?

Comment: Anaconda takes a lot of the headache out of setting up python. For example, they provide binaries for many of the packages that are otherwise difficult to build on a Windows machine. They also provide a package manager.  There's a lot you can do using anaconda / conda, but for your purposes this should allow you to get lxml installed without any issues. If you don't want the whole anaconda distribution just install miniconda with whichever version of python you want and then do `conda install lxml` , and you should be good to go.

Comment: I don't understand why it won't work for windows.  Do windows users need to use anaconda?

Comment: Not necessarily, no, but by default windows lacks some of the things needed to build these packages (this is not the case on most *nix systems). I'm sure you could get this to install without going through anaconda, but it will undoubtedly be a hassle because of the quirks of how windows does things. Anaconda was created, in part, to solve this problem.